# Dynamic UITableViewCell based on UILabel

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, dynamic, uilabel

Working with Xamarin.ios and I need my UITableViewCell to adjust its height based on the size (number of lines of text) of a UILabel. I have a custom UITableViewCell where the UILabel is created and the text is set based on user input. The only way I really know how to adjust the height of the cell is in the UITableViewSource class using the `public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)` method.

```
    public class ChatTableSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        public List<MessageDetails> messages;

        public ChatTableSource()
        {

        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            CustomMessageCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as CustomMessageCell;

            // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
            if (cell == null)
                cell = new CustomMessageCell(cellIdentifier);

            tableView.Layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;

            cell.UpdateCell(messages[indexPath.Row].body);

            return cell;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return messages.ToArray().Length;
        }

        //public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        //{
        //    return dynamic size
        //}

    }
```

```
    public class CustomMessageCell : UITableViewCell
    {

        UILabel body;

        public CustomMessageCell(NSString cellId) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
        {

            body = new UILabel();
        
            ContentView.Add(body);
        }

        public void UpdateCell(string body)
        {
            this.body.Text = body;
        }



        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();

            body.Frame = new CGRect(distanceFromScreenEdge, ContentView.Bounds.Top, longTextSize, ContentView.Bounds.Height);
                
            body.Lines = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with Xamarin - so I can't test this - but this should be what you want to do...

Use constraints and let auto-layout handle the sizing for you.

```
public class CustomMessageCell : UITableViewCell
{

    UILabel body;

    public CustomMessageCell(NSString cellId) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
    {

        body = new UILabel();
    
        ContentView.Add(body);

        var margins = View.LayoutMarginsGuide;

        // Pin the leading edge of body to the margin
        body.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo (margins.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;

        // Pin the trailing edge of body to the margin
        body.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo (margins.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;

        // Pin the top edge of body to the margin
        body.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo (margins.TopAnchor).Active = true;

        // Pin the bottom edge of body to the margin
        body.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo (margins.BottomAnchor).Active = true;

        // set body number of lines to Zero so it will automatically set its own height
        body.Lines = 0

    }

    public void UpdateCell(string body)
    {
        this.body.Text = body;
    }

}
```

You don't need `LayoutSubviews()` at all.